# Webpack throws out from watch mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm learning React and am using it with webpack. The problem is that webpack in `watch mode` builds the files once and then stops. The output in the console looks like this:

```
usesa@pinkya-spot:/var/www/eduonix-react/part-5$ sudo npm run dev
> part-5@1.0.0 dev /var/www/eduonix-react/part-5
> webpack -d --watch


Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 8e2c8a589d1d818bde57
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 943ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
app.bundle.js  1.88 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [14] ./src/index.js 470 bytes {0} [built]
  [27] ./src/App.js 2.42 kB {0} [built]
    + 26 hidden modules
usesa@pinkya-spot:/var/www/eduonix-react/part-5$
```

I pushed all my code to GitHub. It's in the folder "part-5". [Link](https://github.com/PinkyRabbit/eduonix-react/tree/master/part-5) What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you facing any issues in running application? I have tested your app everything working well!

Comment: All works but watch mode runs once and then throws out. Ubuntu 16

Comment: I am also using Ubuntu 16 and in my machine working well(without throwing out). May be issue will relate to version of `node` you are using. What version of node you are using?

Comment: Node 9.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution was to set `max_user_watches`. This command fix all for me:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```